# How to fix 'zsh: command not found: airflow'?

Tags: installation, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to install airflow in my python environment within a linux server and zsh shell. I was able to pip install successfully using the command:

```
pip --proxy http://xxxxx install --user --no-cache-dir -U --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --force-reinstall apache-airflow
```

I can also import airflow from JupyterLab but when I tried airflow version or airflow initdb. It is prompting

```
zsh: command not found: airflow
```

Would appreciate any thoughts on this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the output of `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the following line to my `.zshrc`.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin
```

I then ran `source ~/.zshrc` and Airflow worked.

This is a downside of installing miniconda with `brew cask` I suppose.